# Filtering a query using Node JS and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, filter

I am new to MangoDB and Node JS. I have always worked on SQL databases and I do not know the syntax of MongoDB well. I wanna try to filter the array that I receive from a MongoDB database. I know that JavaScript has a `.filter()` function to filter just the results that contain a string. Is it best practice to get all the objects from MongoDB and filter in Node or do I let MongoDB do the filtering?

My Node.JS project is a back-end project using Node.JS and Express to do CRUD operations on a MongoDB database. In the request I send a parameter called 'equalTo' that contains the value that should be filtered on.

```
var router = express.Router();
var Plot = require("./models/plot");

...

router.get("/plots", (req, res) => {
   let query = "" + req.query.equalTo;
   Plot.find((err, plots) => {
      if (err) {
         res.send(err);
      }
      res.json(plots);
   });
});
```

The filtering should be an OR filter where all results where either the `name` or the `cropName` should CONTAIN the value of the string. If it is possible I would also like the comparison to ignore uppercase's. Here is a schema for the `Plot` object:

```
const plotSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   area: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   comments: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   cropGroupName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   cropName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   plotId: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
   },
   coords: {
      type: [],
      required: true
   },
}, {
   collection: "plots"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is the following:

```
Plot.find({$or:[{name: "anyname"},{cropName:"othername"}]})
```

For further information you can read here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/
You may replace the strings above in your case with equalTo.

Comment: Thanks. The only question I still have is how do i combine this with a contains and ignoring uppercase?

Comment: @user3566338 You can try some regular expression over the string.

Comment: { name: { $regex: ".*" + query + ".*", $options: "i" } }. This did the trick.

Comment: BTW, if you are building in React you may consider doing filtering over there, just an idea.